# "this" undefined inside of a Promise.all().then()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, this

I'm trying to perform `this.setState(…)` inside a `Promise.all(…).then(…)` - i.e. a function after resolving a Promise, 
but it seems that `this` is `undefined` inside of `then(…)`.

After doing some reading, I found that (`this`) needs to be bound inside of `then(…)`.
But, I'm not clear on how to bind it.

below is my original code.

```
var productSource = await this.state.productAll.filter(
  product => product.exchangeId === exchange.exchangeId
);
var productOptions = await this.state.productAll.filter(
  product => product.exchangeId !== exchange.exchangeId
);

Promise.all([productSource, productOptions])
  .then((promises) => {
  this.setState({
    currentExchange: exchange,
    currentCurrency: exchange.baseCurrency,
    originExchange: exchange,
    productSource: promises[0],
    productOptions: promises[1]
  });
  this.refresh();
});
```

Is below correct way of doing this?

```
var productSource = await this.state.productAll.filter(
  product => product.exchangeId === exchange.exchangeId
);
var productOptions = await this.state.productAll.filter(
  product => product.exchangeId !== exchange.exchangeId
);

Promise.all([productSource, productOptions])
  .then((promises) => {
    this.setState({
    currentExchange: exchange,
    currentCurrency: exchange.baseCurrency,
    originExchange: exchange,
    productSource: promises[0],
    productOptions: promises[1]
  });
  this.refresh();
}).bind(this);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with `.then` I think - if you're using an arrow function, the `this` reference is inherited from the surrounding block.

Comment: are there other possible reason for this being undefined inside .then ?

Comment: I would've thought `this` would be undefined in `var productSource = await this.state.productAll.filter` as well ... because the `this` inside `.then` would be the same `this` as in that code

Comment: Are you sure you even need `Promise.all()` here? The idea of `await` is that it essentially pauses execution until the promise waited for resolves. So `productSource` will already be a *collection of products*, not a *promise* of a collection (unless `this.state.productAll.filter` has some really unusual definition).

Comment: Also, unless `this.state.productAll` (or `filter`) returns a promise (which at least to me seems like an odd design), you don't even need to use `await`.

Comment: You really should use `const … = await Promise.all(…);` instead of `Promise.all(…).then(… => …)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the `this` of `this.setState` has proper context, I think here is a good convention to follow, binding `this` in constructor makes sure it corresponds to this component class which owns `setState` method.

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.transaction = this.transaction.bind(this);
}

transaction(exchange, promises) {
  this.setState({
      currentExchange: exchange,
      currentCurrency: exchange.baseCurrency,
      originExchange: exchange,
      productSource: promises[0],
      productOptions: promises[1]
  });
}


...


Promise.all([productSource, productOptions])
  .then((promises) => {
    this.transaction(exchange, promises);
    this.refresh();
  });
```